# Conditional aggregation into a mean value

Tags: r

I have the following situation:

```
  ID           VAR       HSP     VAR2      CODE
00001           56        B       345       1       
00001           52        B       306       1       
00002           5         C       32        2       
00002           22        A       31        2       
00003           55        D       23        1       
00003           5         E       87        1
```

What I need to do is to: for replicated IDs perform the mean of VAR and VAR2 (i.e. all the numeric variables. I have many other numeric columns). The mean should not be done for the column code. Moreover since I have different types of HSP for the final data frame I need to keep the first as it appears in the sorting. The same for the column code.

Desired output:

```
  ID           VAR       HSP     VAR2      CODE
00001           54        B       325.5     1       
00002           13.5      C       31.5      2       
00003           30        D       55        1
```

Edit: the case with 0s:

```
  ID           VAR       HSP     VAR2      CODE
00001           56        B       345       1       
00001           0         B       306       1       
00002           5         C       32        2       
00002           22        A       0         2       
00003           55        D       23        1       
00003           5         E       87        1
```

Desired output:

```
  ID           VAR       HSP     VAR2      CODE
00001           56        B       325.5     1       
00002           13.5      C       32        2       
00003           30        D       55        1
```

So if there are 0s the mean should not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, you can summarise the IDs like this.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(VAR = mean(VAR), HSP = first(HSP), VAR2 = mean(VAR2), CODE = first(CODE))
```

For a more generalized solution, here's how you get the mean for all numerical columns and the first value for all non-numerical values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(~ is.numeric(.x)), mean),
            across(where(~ !is.numeric(.x)), first))
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify to do that only if not 0? So the mean should be done only if there are not 0s.

Comment: @NewUsr Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: So, I ask the mean of the values that are not 0s. For example: if var = 56 for 0001 and instead of 52, it is 0, do not perform the mean

Comment: @NewUsr What VAR value should 0001 then have instead in the desired output?

Comment: @NewUsr If you replace the 0s with NA, you'll have the mean return NA if there are any in the group. I.e: `across(where(~ is.numeric(.x)), ~mean(ifelse(.x == 0, NA, .x)))`

Comment: so this not my case. I will edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: @NewUsr Add the argument `na.rm=TRUE` to return the mean of the remaining non-zero value. I.e. `across(where(~ is.numeric(.x)), ~mean(ifelse(.x == 0, NA, .x), na.rm=TRUE))`